# Android SlidingTabLayout with icons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tabstrip

I am using google's SlidingTabLayout in my view, but i want to add icons to the tabs. I'm using this http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html
Can anyone please help?

```
void setUpPager(View view){
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity()));
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
  }
```

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
      android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125794/slidingtablayout-with-icons-only

Comment: I needed it, so I changed codes of SlidingTabLayout little bit to make it easy to use icon for tabs https://github.com/kimkevin/SlidingIconTabLayout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId)` to inflate a custom layout for the `SlidingTabLayout` tab views.

When `SlidingTabLayout` tries to populate the tab strips, initially looks for any specified layout resource to inflate. Otherwise, it inflates default tab view.

Comment: Should i need to create a LinearLayout with icon and textView for each and everytab?

Comment: Just create one layout and supply the resource id of it and the title textview to the method, SlidingTabLayout will inflate it for all your tabs itself.

Comment: I'm already setting a ViewPager Adapter and now am setting this customTabView also. But i'm still seeing the old tabs only

Comment: I'm using a ViewPager which has an adapter http://pastebin.com/HjwTjVEX . This adapter sets the pagetitle.

Comment: but what if i want only icons? Why do I need to set a textview

Comment: TextView is just an option to you. Remove all references to textviews and inflate a new View and before return it personalize the icon,

Comment: @user1159517, you have set customTabView and then set adapter in viewpager.

Comment: I needed it, so I changed codes of SlidingTabLayout little bit to make it easy to use icon for tabs https://github.com/kimkevin/SlidingIconTabLayout

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Can we use this method to display a different icon per tab?

Comment: i wan to display two textview in tabs but this is not working @user1159517

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski  
i wan to display two textview in tabs but this is not working

Answer (score 16):

Just want to give example for the Correct and accepted answer. :)
Firstly, add the tabs and set their custom view when you are adding the adapter to your viewpager. For example see following lines:

```
mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

//Do something with your view before setting up adapter

ViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) View().findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_title, R.id.tabtext);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Where `sliding_tabs` are the tabs_titles to be added and are defined in `xml` file of the `viewpager` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.packagename.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        tools:context=".ActivityUser"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and where `custom_tab_title` is a separate `xml` file in your `layout` folder.For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/titletab">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and you can set the image for a particular tab by:

```
Drawable tab_image = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("image_name_in_drawable", "drawable", "com.packagename"));
tab_image.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);  //Setting up the resolution for image
ImageSpan imageSpanresource = new ImageSpan(tab_image);
//Notice the additional space at the end of the String
resourcesstring = "Tab1 ";
//here we are setting up the position to display image..
SpannableString viewpager_tab_title = new SpannableString(resourcesstring ); 
viewpager_tab_title.setSpan(imageSpanresource, resourcesstring.length()-1, resourcesstring.length(), 0);
```

**Notice** that I have added an additional space to the `viewpager_tab_title` and am setting up the image to that position, so that the actual string is displayed completely.

Comment: +1, Your answer is perfect and working fine, however, you are using `resourcesstring` in the end which might confuse others (it confused me ;) ). So, I am editing your answer slightly.

Comment: Yes,  that might Confuse others. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 13):

To customize SlidingTabLayout the way you want, you only need to modify the method populateTabStrip(). With this approach, you do not need care about any TextView.

```
public void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;

            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, mTabStrip,
                    false);

            ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_icon);
            iconImageView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(getIconResourceArray()[i]));

            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        }
}
```

Your layout could be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The way you implement the getResourceArray() method is up to you. Here is how I did:

```
public class IconSlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    private Integer[] mIconResourceArray;

    ...

    public Integer[] getIconResourceArray() {
        return mIconResourceArray;
    }

    public void setIconResourceArray(Integer[] mIconResourceArray) {
        this.mIconResourceArray = mIconResourceArray;
    }
}
```

In the activity:

```
mSlidingTabLayout = (IconSlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.icon_sliding_tab_layout);
Integer[] iconResourceArray = { R.drawable.news_tab_icon,
        R.drawable.challenges_tab_icon, R.drawable.trophies_tab_icon,
        R.drawable.leaderboard_tab_icon };
mSlidingTabLayout.setIconResourceArray(iconResourceArray);
```

Be aware that in order to have access to R.layout.tab_layout*, you have to import yourpackage.R instead of android.R as it is by default in SlidingTabStrip.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks! For those of you wanting to do the same, please note that you don't have to create a separate class called IconSlidingTabLayout. If you want, you can just add those 3 methods to Google's SlidingTabLayout java file and you are ready to go.

Comment: I'm getting an error of `HorizontalScrollView` again and again.

Comment: how do we set the `tab_layout_icon` height and width, spread evenly instead of hard coding it?