# Android ViewPager with icons

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm creating a SlidingPageLayout but it does not have icons. I'm setting a viewPager for this slidingpageLayout. The viewpager has a PagerAdapter and PagerAdapter sets the title of the page. I want to set an icon instead of a text.
Reference question: [Android SlidingTabLayout with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420293/android-slidingtablayout-with-icons/23420356?noredirect=1#comment35890691_23420356)

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you

```
Actionbar mActionbar = getActionbar();
mActionBar.setTitle("");
mActionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1))

mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mActionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1))
                break;
            case 1:
                mActionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2))
                break;
            default:
                mActionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1))
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: My Sliding table Layout setup: http://pastebin.com/EM01Ai2d
My View Pager code: http://pastebin.com/HjwTjVEX