# How to change SlidingTabLayout title to Icon

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a SlidingTabsLayout in my application. I took help from [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) Android Developer.It works fine. I want to display an icon instead of text as navigation tabs as with Facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Icons to SlidingTabLayout instead of Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472759/add-icons-to-slidingtablayout-instead-of-text)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472759/add-icons-to-slidingtablayout-instead-of-text

Comment: I need images in selected state also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420293/android-slidingtablayout-with-icons

Comment: I needed it, so I changed codes of SlidingTabLayout little bit to make it easy to use icon for tabs https://github.com/kimkevin/SlidingIconTabLayout