# Custom Action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have developed an Android application which has 4 TabHost's which are in fragments.

I Know how to customize the `ActionBar` in MainActivity.

But problem is how can I customize my `ActionBar` according to the 4 different TabHost's in different `Fragment`s?

Here is my tabHost code -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    /** Creating ANDROID Tab */
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            //.setText("Android")

            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<PlayFragment01>(this, "play", 
    PlayFragment01.class))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.playtabhosticon);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);


    /** Creating APPLE Tab */
    Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab()
            //.setText("Apple")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<VenueFragment01>(this, "venu", 
    VenueFragment01.class))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.venutabhosticon);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);  

    /** Creating APPLE Tab */
    Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab()
            //.setText("Apple")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<SocialFragment01>(this, "social", SocialFragment01.class))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.socialtabhosticon);

    actionBar.addTab(tab3);  

    /** Creating APPLE Tab */
    Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab()
            //.setText("Apple")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<ActivityFragment01>(this, "activity",         
   ActivityFragment01.class))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.actionbartabhosticon);

    actionBar.addTab(tab4);  



}   
}
```

Here is my first fragment code -

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarnavtab;
 /** This is a listfragment class */
 public class PlayFragment01 extends Fragment {

/** An array of items to display in ArrayList */



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)    
{
    /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play, container, false);         
    //new DownloadJSON().execute();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0077d1")));
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    getActivity().getActionBar().setIcon(
       new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));    
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar2, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you wan't to customize exactly?

Comment: @RolfSmit action bar...

Comment: "I Know how to customize the ActionBar"....

Comment: Do you want to style the actionbar from within a Fragment?

Comment: @RolfSmit Yes... let me be more clear from giving an example like if my first fragment open then there should be an setting button and if second fragment open there should be other button working different on action bar.

Comment: Question unclear + `ActionBar.setNavigationMode()` is now deprecated

Comment: @shkschneider it for image tabHost can you suggested me other way that I can use images in my tabhost

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set custom ActionBar color / style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288402/how-to-set-custom-actionbar-color-style)

Answer (score 0):

The question your asking is not very clear but you can get the ActionBar instance from within a Fragment using `getActivity().getActionBar()`.

Comment: Thanks!! Above I had explain it with an example also!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it. This will help other users having the same problem to quickly solve it.

Comment: I work with this but this is not solving my problem here is my fragment code - "/** This is a listfragment class */
public class PlayFragment01 extends Fragment {
 
 /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
 
 
 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play, container, false);   
  //new DownloadJSON().execute();
  
  
  
  return rootView;
 }
}"

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBar.setNavigationMode()` and `TabHost` is now deprecated.

The new `ToolBar` introduced in API-21 is more powerfull.

But since you asked for a solution, here is a simple one from Google [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html):
This is like a `PagerTabStrip` that you can easily customize and works like great.

It works with `ViewPager` and `Fragments` of course.

Comment: But How can I add images in that ToolBars can you give me an example of it!!

Comment: @madhavan As always, you can customize Views https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472759/add-icons-to-slidingtablayout-instead-of-text

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view ,you should read this ,so that you can get the basic idea for creating a fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Try this sample code..this sample code includes 3 tab ,first try to understand this code ,then you can make your own app with 4 tabs

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Also try to modify your question ,It is unclear  and also it will be good that you post your errors

Comment: Thanks!! I had read full block. I have an query How can I add images in places of this text ?

Comment: do you mean to change the title name of tabs)top rated ,games to image or the text inside the tab to image?

Comment: read this link :-http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/ If you find this useful you can accept my answer

Comment: Thanks it help a lot!! can you please tell me if I want to make background of tab - white color what I do please help me!!

Comment: Inside manifest file :-
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" instead of this ,use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
then Build the project then clean it.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Light').

Comment: which link are you following?...first link or second one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64173/discussion-between-madhavan-and-user3173628).

Comment: your second link code is deprecate!! so I search some other code and using other!!