# SlidingTabLayout change color selected icon

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using the SlidingTabLayout with spannable so as the Title I've got the icons. How can I change the icon color for selected?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26934274/4409113

Comment: I've already try this. But this change the text color. It won't change the spannable string color.

Comment: Try this:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/pull/62/files?short_path=04c6e90

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
        new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabSelectedIconColor);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabUnselected(tab);
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabUnselectedIconColor);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabReselected(tab);
            }
        }
);
```