# Add custom view to tab

Tags: android

I want to add custom view for my tabs.I researched the internet but I can't find good tutorial.I am adding tabs with this code in `onCreate` event.

```
        private String[] tabs = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2"};
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

I don't have any xml file for tabs.

How can I do this ? Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

first of all i suggest you use :

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

and do not use actionbar tabs.

that is a source code of tabs of `google play` app.
after that you can create your own layout use `mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId)` to inflate a custom layout for the SlidingTabLayout tab views. look at:

[Android SlidingTabLayout with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420293/android-slidingtablayout-with-icons)

for complete example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
          android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewpager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in your `fragment` or `activity`:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

your adapter of `mViewPager` must override below method

```
 @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return your tab title;
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

first step is creating custom layout for each tabs so:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

then when you want to add tabs to actionbar you must do :

```
    ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab);
    TextView txt1 = (TextView)tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txt1.setText("Tab 1");
```

Comment: I can't change my tab system.Because I am using this:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1   Is there another way ?

Comment: why? every thing here is straight forward , all you need is just add that in layout and set viewpager for it and also overwrite getTitle(), if you want i can post code to run it ! but anyway do what you like!!

Comment: I will try.But I don't want to change my system because I finished everything in my project this is the last problem for me.

Comment: do whatever you like my brother ;-) but i do not think you need a lot change !!

Comment: Can you review my code ? Is this avaible for change ? This is main : http://pastebin.com/MgkWFBr2 and this is xml http://pastebin.com/vpELpNF3

Comment: i could not open www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1 so i do not know exactly what you have implemented. you sync viewpager by tabs, do not you? everything is ok but what is `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"` i have no idea about your project so i do not say ok and then you will get in trouble, i must at least see your main activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60250/discussion-between-tolgay-toklar-and-mmlooloo).

Comment: i have solved it in two ways (actionbar and SlidingTab) and will post it in 12hrs know i must go somewhere , do not be worry about that!!

Comment: i can show badge but after that the click listener dose not work, am trying to fix it!!

Comment: i also implement it in another way but : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584010/badgeview-and-slidingtabstrip-clicking-error