# how to add red color badges(notification count) overlay like facebook in android

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-tabstrip

I am using SlidingTabLayout provided by [Google](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) but i dont know how to add badge on top of tab's text like in this screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated alot.

I have already done showing text and icon image both side by side but i dont how to show notification like overlay text. As you can see in this image notification text is over the icon image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);

BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);

badge.setText("1");

badge.show();

**Go to Here**

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: It is quite old apporach and it does not use new slidingtablayout

Answer (score 0):

As you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420356/3735097) , user [Nikola Despotoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557179/nikola-despotoski) already answered on your question.

> Use
>
> ```
> mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId)
> ```
>
> to inflate a custom layout for the `SlidingTabLayout` tab
>   views.
>
> When `SlidingTabLayout` tries to populate the tab strips, initially
>   looks for any specified layout resource to inflate. Otherwise, it
>   inflates default tab view.

Comment: i used this to show image and text side by side but i am not sure how can i use it to show overlay text on image

Comment: @Aditya Try [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c04512ffc74a28a19e4). I found it on the web.

Comment: @Aditya What is problem with that icon. You inflate your own layout, so you can put there anything